# How to read in numbers from a txt file and make sure they exist

Tags: c++

I have a text file that only contains one integer, even though it's supposed to contain at least two integers.

[image]

I need to read the first value (which is `2` in this case), and store it to `positiveIntegerOne`. If the file doesn’t contain any numbers, then display the error message “Input file exists but has no value”. Then, read the second value (in this case, the second value doesn’t exist). If the second value exists, store it to `positiveIntegerTwo`, if the number doesn’t exist, then display the error message “Input file has odd number of values.”

Here is the logic:

```
read first integer from file intInput.dat into positiveIntegerOne

     if end-of-file on intInput.dat
         display error message “Input file exists but has no values”


read second integer from file intInput.dat into positiveIntegerTwo

    if end-of-file on intInput.dat
        display error message “Input file has odd number of values”
```

Here is my attempt:

```
inFile >> positiveIntegerOne;
    if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerOne)) {
        cout << "Input file exists but has no values \n";
        return 1;

    }

    inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo;
    if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo)) {
        cout << "Input file has odd number of values \n";
        return 1;
    }
```

But whenever I run the code, it will display both error messages, even if I do have one number in my file.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 but the code will display both error messages somehow. In this case, it should only display the second error message because my file has odd number of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show attempts to read *four* values:

```
// This reads one value into positiveIntegerOne
inFile >> positiveIntegerOne;

// This reads a second value into positiveIntegerOne
if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerOne)) {
```

Same with `positiveIntegerTwo`, for a total of four inputs.

You need to think about the logic of your program: It should attempt to read the first value, and only if that succeeds it should attempt to read the second value.

Perhaps something like this:

```
if (inFile >> positiveIntegerOne) {
    if (inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo) {
        // Both values successfully read, do something with them
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not read the second value\n";
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Could not read the first value\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But this code will display both error messages if there no value in the file to begin with...

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
inFile >> positiveIntegerOne;
```

then a number is extracted from the stream. The one number in your file is no longer in the stream. Then you continue with

```
if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerOne)) {
        cout << "Input file exists but has no values \n";
        return 1;

}

inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo;
if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo)) {
        cout << "Input file has odd number of values \n";
        return 1;
}
```

but as there is no more number in the stream you see both errors. Probably you wanted this:

```
if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerOne)) {
        cout << "Input file exists but has no values \n";
        return 1;    
}
if (!(inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo)) {
        cout << "Input file has odd number of values \n";
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So I have another question now, I tried your code. It works perfectly fine if there is one integer in the file, it will display the second error message only. But then, if there no value in the txt file, your code will display both error messages...

Comment: @EmmaG this code is incomplete so I cannot tell for sure. If this is inside a function you could put a `return;` inside the first `if`

Comment: I updated my question and uploaded the full code, I couldn't put return in the if statement somehow, bec if I do the console box will automatically disappear after I run the code

Comment: @EmmaG please dont vandalize your own question. If you have a new/follow-up quesiton you can open a new question. Both answers given do answer your question as it stood at the time of writing the answers, changing your question afterwards isnt nice

Comment: @EmmaG anyhow, if the block is not inside a function then just put it inside a function so that you can use `return;`

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I am new to this site, I will post a new questions next time :)

Comment: @EmmaG no big deal, just consider that it is not a forum where more interaction between asker and answerer is natural. The Q&As are meant to stay and eventually be useful also for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Try inFile.close() before return.

And read the file contents through the "while".

And It is better to modify the code style as follows:

```
int n;
if(inFile.eof())
{
  cout << "Input file exists but has no values \n";
  inFile.close();
  return 1;
}
do
{
  inFile >> n;
  if(n % 2 == 1)
  {
    cout << "Input file has odd number of values \n";
    inFile.close();
    return 1;
  }
} while (!inFile.eof());
```